# Sequence: last_value billions bigger that actual count of rows

Tags: postgresql, sequence

In my PostgreSQL 9.6 database, `INSERT` on a certain table is not possible anymore: The primary key column is an integer and the `last_value` of the sequence in question is 2,147,484,010 - which is too big for an integer. As a consequence, I get 'integer out of range'.

So far, so good.

The question is: How come? Why is `last_value` so huge?

The actual count of rows is just 112,698. The table rows are not deleted normally.

And there seems to be no general, reproducible problem. I've tried with the following: I copied that database, deleted all rows from the table in question, reset the sequence, and created entries with an (almost) 'real life query'. I could create more than 6 million rows with any problems.

I know that sequences are not designed to be gapless (e.g. on the above-mentioned test I got a `last_value` of 8,946,095 for 6,404,000 rows), however having a value 2 billion bigger than the row count seem pretty strange to me. Obviously, something went wrong here.

How could I debug this further?

**Edit: data of the sequence is as follows:**

```
+------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| last_value | start_value | increment_by | max_value             | min_value | cache_value | log_cnt | is_cycled | is_called |
| 2147484010 | 1           | 1            | 9,22337203685478E+018 | 1         | 1           | 32      | False     | True      |
+------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: How are your sequence values distributed in your table?

Comment: What's the cache size for the sequence?

Comment: @mustaccio `cache_value` is 1. See my edit.

Comment: @Lennart Cannot tell, unfortunately, since the actual values of the column are sort of hashed by  `pseudo_encrypt`.

Comment: What does `select max(id)` from that table give you? Maybe something/someone ran `select nextval('...') from generate_series(1,1e10)`  or something similar and burned those numbers. Under "normal" circumstances it takes ages to reach the "end" of a sequence. I don't think you will find out _how_ that happened after the fact. Just reset the sequence to `max(id)` and move on

Comment: If you're refering to [that pseudo_encrypt](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt), it's reversible.

Comment: @Daniel Vérité Yes, I mean this function. How is it reversible?

Comment: By reapplying it on the result. `pseudo_encrypt(pseudo_encrypt(x))` returns `x`.

Comment: @Daniel Vérité I don't get it. `SELECT pseudo_encrypt(1);` returns `561465857`. So, in order to get the reverse result, it should be possible, to pass in `561465857` and get back `1`. However, `SELECT pseudo_encrypt(pseudo_encrypt(561465857));` returns `561465857` and not `1`. So, that's not the way to find out what has been the original sequence value for the row with the id `561465857`.

Comment: `pseudo_encrypt(1)` returns `56146585`. It gets stored in the table. Later if you do `pseudo_encrypt(561465857)` it returns `1` which is the original value.